# Spark read csv schema

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the below code to import a file into dataframe. Even though, I have defined schema, somehow it is not using the schema I have provided. Any insights?

```
schema= "row INT, name STRING, age INT, count INT"
df = spark.read.format('csv').\
options(schema = schema).\
options(delimiter=',').\
options(header='false').\
load('C:/SparkCourse/fakefriends.csv')
df.columns
['_c0', '_c1', '_c2', '_c3']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Can you try with this.

schema= "row INT, name STRING, age INT, count INT"
df = spark.read.format("csv")
        .schema(schema)
        .options(delimiter=',')
        .options("header", "false")
        load('C:/SparkCourse/fakefriends.csv')
        df.columns
        ['_c0', '_c1', '_c2', '_c3']
```

Comment: Hi @Nisha, this code is throwing error as you have used option and not options. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for correction. while dropping the loc here missed it!!!

Comment: Thank you - this worked. So as i understand I needed to change schema(schema)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this for correct solution.

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

schema = "row INT, name STRING, age INT, count INT"

spark.read.format("csv") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .options(delimiter=',') \
    .options(header=False) \
    .load('fakefriends.csv') \
    .show(truncate=False)

+---+----+---+-----+
|row|name|age|count|
+---+----+---+-----+
|1  |a   |1  |2    |
|2  |b   |2  |3    |
|3  |c   |3  |4    |
+---+----+---+-----+
```